# How to make span work being outside of the anchor to work like its inside of it

Tags: html, css

I have a markup like which i have given below :
    I have given some link to the anchor tag but I want user to click anywhere on the li tag to make link redirect to link given to anchor tag but i cannot place my span inside the anchor tag ,it has to be outside of the anchor tag.what will be the css for that and it should work in IE also.

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <span> 1 </span>
       <a href="">Click any where in the li i will take u to somewhere</a> 
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: insert your li's inside anchor tag , and apply CSS for styling . Simple

Comment: Why can't the `span` be inside the anchor tag?

Comment: @torazaburo Because some dynamic content will replace the content inside the anchor tag

Comment: @CodingAnt i want it to be worked in this format

Comment: Is the `<span>` a counter of some kind?

Comment: @DavidThomas check out jsfilddle http://jsfiddle.net/bhatvicky59/9w7ffLzz/  Now the problem is its not working in IE below 11

Comment: So the `<span>` *is* a counter of some kind? Why not drop that, and just use an `<ol>`, and style with `list-style-type: decimal;` for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the document object model with css. You would need a javascript function for that.

Comment: Expanding the padding to include the span technically didn't modify the DOM, but it work as intended.So, cool trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
<li onlick="window.location.href='your.url'"> ... </li>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike but i need to do this using html m css :)

Comment: Then as far as I know that is impossible.

Comment: here is how it works checkout the link http://jsfiddle.net/bhatvicky59/9w7ffLzz/ Now the problem is its not working in IE below 11...

Comment: In IE actually, what happens when i hover on number like 1, 2 etc it does not work like link ,it behaves just as a simple text